# Openlayers overview map interferes with loading

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using Openlayers 3.16.0 and this bug has really stumped me.

Whenever I turn on my overview map layers start loading more slowly and after a while just not anymore at all. Like this: [image: not loading]

Is this an OL bug that got fixed in a later version, or am I doing something wrong here maybe?

**EDIT:**

Tested with 3.18 and it's still doing it...

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is a bit limited, but wanted to try add my 2 cents as I had the same issue and ended up just not using 1 of my map layers. Turns out it was just too many tiles. If you have another layer, you can specify it when you set up your OverviewMap.

```
layers: [
            new TileLayer({
                source: your_good_layer
            })
```